# Can't export data table to excel from jsf page

Tags: java, html, excel, jsf, primefaces

I'm using jsf pages with prime faces 3.5  , my data table works fine on html page and all data showing in correct rows and coulmns

but my problem when hit excel icon to export all the data 
i get it as in the link :
http://content.screencast.com/users/tl4s.com.sa/folders/Default/media/40664996-d060-41f8-8a8c-428c114d57c1/excel.jpg

sample from my html code :

```
            <h:form id="hesham1">
            <p:scrollPanel style="width:100%;height:100%">
                <p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}" id="hesham"
                    encoding="windows-1256" dir="rtl"
                    emptyMessage="لا يوجد بيانات او تأكد من البيانات المستعلم عنها">
                    <f:facet name="header">  
        تقرير عن صف 
    </f:facet>

                    <p:columnGroup type="header">
                        <p:row>


                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="2" headerText="معلومات الطالب"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الاولى"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الثانية"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الثالثة"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الرابعة"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة الخامسة"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة السادسة"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column colspan="3" headerText="الحصة السابعة"
                                style="text-align: center;" />
                        </p:row>

                        <p:row>
                            <p:column headerText="اسم الطالب" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="التاريخ" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="المعلم" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الماده" style="text-align: center;" />
                            <p:column headerText="الحاله" style="text-align: center;" />
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>



                    <p:column>  
        #{car.student_name}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.date}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.teachers}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.course}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.state}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.teachers2}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.course2}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.state2}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.teachers3}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.course3}  
    </p:column>

                    <p:column>  
        #{car.state3}  
    </p:column>



                    <f:facet name="footer">  
        اجمالي عدد الاستعلامات #{fn:length(tableBean.carsSmall)}   
    </f:facet>

                </p:dataTable>
            </p:scrollPanel>
            <br />

            <h:commandButton value="طباعة التقرير" type="button"
                icon="ui-icon-print">
                <p:printer target="hesham" />
            </h:commandButton>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style3.css"
                media="print" />
            <p:panel header="Export Page Data">
                <h:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage value="/css/excel.png" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="hesham" fileName="cars" />
                </h:commandLink>

                <h:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage value="/css/pdf.png" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="hesham" fileName="cars" />
                </h:commandLink>

                <h:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage value="/css/csv.png" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="hesham" fileName="cars" />
                </h:commandLink>

                <h:commandLink>
                    <p:graphicImage value="/css/xml.png" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="xml" target="hesham" fileName="cars" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your values inside outputtext tags, like this:

```
  <p:column>  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.date}"/>  
    </p:column>
```