# Primefaces data exporter exports empty values in Excel

Tags: excel, jsf-2, primefaces, export

I  try to export some data loded from database.

With the code below, the exported file shows empty values in all columns althought my variable `marchebean.selectedmarche.marchetraveau` contains values.

Is there anything wrong in my code ?

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and this is my xhtml page

```
     <h:form id="form">
        <p:tabView>
           <p:tab title="Visualiser ">
              <p:panel>
                 <h:commandLink >
                    <p:commandButton value="exporter" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="crs" fileName="prixde"  pageOnly="true" />
                 </h:commandLink>
                 <p:dataTable id="crs" var="marche" value="#{marchebean.selectedmarche.marchetraveau}" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                          Tbaleau des travaux
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                       <h3>  Total HTVA = #{marchebean.calculdetotaltravhtva()}</h3>
                       <h3> Total TTC = #{marchebean.calculdetotaltravttc()} </h3>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="article" width="10%"  >
                       <h:outputText value="#{marche.traveaux.article}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Désignation des  traveaux" width="40%" >
                       <h:outputText value="#{marche.traveaux.designation}"/>
                       <h:outputText value="#{marche.traveaux.paragraph}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Unité">
                       <h:outputText value="#{marche.traveaux.unite}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="PUHTVA">
                       <h:outputText value="#{marche.prixunitaire}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="PUTTC">
                       <h:outputText value="#{marchebean.calcultva(marche.prixunitaire)}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Qtt">
                       <h:outputText value="#{marche.quantite}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="MHTVA">
                       <h:outputText value="#{marchebean.calculmonthtva(marche.prixunitaire ,marche.quantite)}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="MTTC">
                       <h:outputText value="#{marchebean.calculmontttc(marche.prixunitaire ,marche.quantite)}" />
                    </p:column>
                 </p:dataTable>
              </p:panel>
           </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
     </h:form>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't export data table to excel from jsf page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217879/cant-export-data-table-to-excel-from-jsf-page)

Comment: @EmilKaminski : thank you for response my problem is different , i have empty columns in exel file and although i changed values into columns to <h:outputText value=""/> the same error still persist!!

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem. Create a simple datatable with one column outside any panels and tabs and see if it works? If yes add more columns... if it still works try to work on until you catch the problem.

Answer (score 1):

we need to provide the

```
<f:facet name="header>
    <h:outputText value="aricle"/>
</f:facet>
```

then  exporter will add the headers to your exported document.

```
<p:column headerText="article" width="10%"  >  
        <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="article" />
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{car.traveaux.article}"/>      
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Maybe it needs validation and that's why it's empty at the end. Adding immediate="true" skips the validation.

```
    <h:form id="confColaForm" .....>
        <p:dataTable id="tablacolas" ... >

            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:commandLink id="exportar" update=":confColaForm:tablacolas" style="align:right;" immediate="true" >
                    <h:graphicImage library="images" name="iconexcel.png" style="width:30px;height:30px; "
                        title="Exportar" />
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="tablacolas" fileName="ConfiguracionColas" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </f:facet>
            ...(columns here)
    </p:dataTable/>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what is different and why

Comment: @Kukeltje the tree is a little bit different, and try adding the immediate="true". Probably it fails because it needs some validation and this skips it. I'll add that to my main comment.

Answer (score 0):

possible reason may be the "managedbean scope"...
1)change scope to "view"
2)serialize managedbean

this worked for me